# Follow site programatically

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, social

In SP 2013 on prem, I am developing a web part using c#. All my functions work except follow/unfollow a site for a user.

So I am turning here for some inspiration, looking for some code snippets or blogs/links. Please share if you got some good references or snippets.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code snippet to follow a site

```
//GET USER PROFILE MANAGER
SPServiceContext serverContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteobject);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(loginName);
if (profile != null)
{
    //Social following manager object for the user's profile
    SPSocialFollowingManager manager = new SPSocialFollowingManager(profile);
    SPSocialActorInfo actorInfo = new SPSocialActorInfo();
    actorInfo.ContentUri = new Uri(url);//url of site to follow
    actorInfo.AccountName = targetUser.LoginName;
    actorInfo.ActorType = SPSocialActorType.Site;
    manager.Follow(actorInfo);
}
```

In case of UnFollow

```
//GET USER PROFILE MANAGER
SPServiceContext serverContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(siteobject);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(loginName);
if (profile != null)
{
    //Social following manager object for the user's profile
    SPSocialFollowingManager manager = new SPSocialFollowingManager(profile);
    SPSocialActorInfo actorInfo = new SPSocialActorInfo();
    actorInfo.ContentUri = new Uri(url);//url of site to unfollow
    actorInfo.AccountName = targetUser.LoginName;
    actorInfo.ActorType = SPSocialActorType.Site;
    manager.StopFollowing(actorInfo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, mate. I am having issues making it work. On  manager.StopFollowing(actorInfo);, I get this error; An exception of type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll but was not handled in user code.  Have you had the same issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Follow Method that takes a SPWeb object and a SPUser object.

```
SPServiceContext serverContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(web.Site);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
string userString = user.LoginName.ToString();
UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(userString);

        if (userProfile != null)
        {
            SPSocialFollowingManager manager = new   
            SPSocialFollowingManager(userProfile);
            SPSocialActorInfo actorInfo = new SPSocialActorInfo();
            actorInfo.ContentUri = new Uri(web.Url);
            actorInfo.AccountName = user.LoginName;
            actorInfo.ActorType = SPSocialActorType.Site;
            manager.Follow(actorInfo);
        }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271133/how-do-i-follow-site-in-sharepoint-2013-with-ssom

here is the MSDN guideline https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163217.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Also this one http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/31/programmatically-follow-documents-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I have tried this code as reference, and many others. I always get an error: An exception of type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll but was not handled in user code. Have you had the same issue, and do you know about any work around ?